# Sqoop Import dataset from Postgresql to Hbase ERROR

Tags: postgresql, hbase, sqoop

I want to import dataset from Postgresql to Hbase.

My Dataset on Postgres is shown using the command:

```
SELECT t.* FROM "poly"."patient" AS t
```

My command to create table on Hbase where I should receive data:

```
create 'patient','contact_id'
```

My scoop command used to import data is :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres --username postgres --password psql -hbase-table patient -column-family contact_id --table patient -- --schema poly

2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64
2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hadoop
2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hadoop
2019-11-10 17:20:23,626 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hadoop
2019-11-10 17:20:23,627 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=127.0.0.1:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x2bb314550x0, quorum=127.0.0.1:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
2019-11-10 17:20:23,661 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2019-11-10 17:20:23,704 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
2019-11-10 17:20:23,720 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x16e55a28e51001d, negotiated timeout = 90000
2019-11-10 17:21:14,008 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Sun Nov 10 17:21:13 EST 2019, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=69278: row 'patient,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=localhost,16020,1573394740591, seqNum=0

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=69278: row 'patient,,' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=localhost,16020,1573394740591, seqNum=0
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:65)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:402)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:360)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:334)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
... 4 more
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:331)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:34094)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:394)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/Gauge
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:224)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yammer.metrics.core.Gauge
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 14 more
```